# Javascript command/variable based on Webpage Domain/Site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code for fetching a latest tweet but I would like the TWITTERUSERNAME
to be different depending on the domain it is on as it's a template that is being called from one place but used across multiple domains.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function() {
        jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/TWITTERUSERNAME.json?callback=?', function(data) {
             jQuery('#tweet').html(data[0].text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm guessing just some kind of if statement in php to replace the TWITTERUSERNAME value in the script?

Any pointers on this would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('document').ready(function() {
<?php
  $usernames = array(
    'domain.com'      => 'twittername1' ,
    'otherdomain.com' => 'twittername2' ,
    'default'         => 'fallbacktwittername'
  );
  if( isset( $usernames[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']] ) ){
    $twittername = $usernames[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']];
  }else{
    $twittername = $usernames['default'];
  }
?>
    jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/<?php echo $twittername; ?>.json?callback=?', function(data) {
       jQuery('#tweet').html(data[0].text);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Caveats/Warnings**
The details in the array ("domain.com","otherdomain.com") would not match any contained subdomains (so "www.domain.com" and "www.otherdomain.com" would be seen as not being the same as "domain.com" and "othersomain.com").

Comment: I've just put this in to place and it's working in theory in that if i put <?php echo $twittername; ?> in standalone code it will show the correct username but for some reason it's not working in the jQuery script

Comment: Don't worry, managed to get it working, moved the code around a little and it's working great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this in php then you can check against the servername

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.example.com'){
    $twit = 'username';
}
?>
```

then your javascript would be something like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(function() {
        jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/<?=$twit?>.json?callback=?', function(data) {
             jQuery('#tweet').html(data[0].text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Very minor thing - using short-tags "<?", as opposed to long-tags "<?php" is not a recommended practice (as some servers will not allow short-tags and that means a long find-and-replace process). So if you changed `<?=$twit?>` to `<?php echo $twit; ?>` it would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "MyServer")
{
  $username = 'Username1';
} elseif($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "MySecondServer")
{
  $username = "Username2";
} else
{
  $username = "DefaultUsername";
}
```

and then you use $username as the twitterusername.